# Hardness of a constrained quadratic maximization

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-hard

Consider the following quadratic maximization:
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} &\quad\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
\mathcal{X} = \lbrace
\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} :~ \|\mathbf{x}\|_{2}=1, \|\mathbf{x}\|_{0}\le k
\rbrace,
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $k \le n$ is a sparsity parameter. 
This problem is NP-hard, by a reduction from the max-clique problem.

I am interested in a similar problem obtained by imposing additional structure on $\mathcal{X}$.
In particular, assume that the $n$ variables in $\mathbf{x}$ are partitioned into $k$ disjoint groups.
We restrict the feasible set to unit-length vectors $\mathbf{x}$ with one active variable per group. 
That is, $\mathcal{X}$ contains again $k$-sparse vectors, but the support cannot be arbitrary; it contains (at most) one nonzero entry for each of the $k$ groups.

Note that the feasible set in the modified problem is a subset of the previous maximization, but the number of feasible supports can still be exponential in the number of variables $n$ (for appropriately chosen $k$).

I suspect that the modified problem is also NP-hard. Any ideas on how to show that (or disprove)? Feel free to share your intuition.

Comment: Without the semidefiniteness requirement, this should be NP-hard by reduction from independent set.  Say $G$ is a graph with $N$ vertices.  Build an instance of your problem with $2N$ variables and $N$ groups, one group per vertex $v$ of $G$.  Setting the first variable in $v$'s group to 1 is like adding $v$ to the independent set; setting the 2nd variable is like not adding $v$ to the set.  Now you can form a matrix $A$ that minimizes the number of edges $(v,w) \in E$ such that both $v,w$ are in the set.  But will this $A$ be semidefinite?  I don't know.

Comment: @D.W., could you just use the laplacian of the adjacency matrix? $L$ is always positive semidefinite.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso, I don't know!  Interesting idea.

Comment: If the only problem is that the argument $\mathbf{A}$ is not positive semidefinite (PSD) ($\mathbf{A}$ is only symmetric), then it should be fine: we can always solve the maximization on $\mathbf{A}+|\lambda_{min}(\mathbf{A})| \cdot \mathbf{I}$. I will take a look at the proposed approach and let you know!

Comment: I have some trouble seeing how to adapt this approach to my problem. For me, $\mathbf{x}$ is not binary; it is a unit-norm real vector, allowed to have negative entries as well, which introduces some difficulty in designing $\mathbf{A}$. Unless, am I missing something obvious? But I did like the idea of the $2N$ variables. I will keep thinking whether I can figure something out building on it.

Comment: Should I move this question to cstheory.stackexchange?

Comment: @m.a., if you don't get an answer after your bounty expires, yes, flagging this for moderator attention to ask them to migrate it to CSTheory would be reasonable.  P.S. I missed your earlier comments (in the future you can notify me with "@D.W."), sorry about that.  You are right, I overlooked that you are working over $\mathbb{R}$ instead of over $\{0,1\}$.  I don't have any idea how to approach your problem.

Comment: @D.W., ok, thanks. Btw, my previous comment was not quite right; even for the simple sparsity constraints problem which is also over $\mathbb{R}$, the reduction uses a combinatorial ({0,1}) problem. It is just that I could not figure out a similar reduction for my case.

Comment: @m.a. With the constrain $\|x\|_2=1$ every coordinate actually fits in the range $[0,1]$. When $\mathbf{A}$ is PSD, the objective function is convex and it reduces to the binary case. Is that right?

Comment: @WillardZhan, I am not sure what you mean. It is true that each coordinate falls in that range. It is also true that with $\mathbf{A}$ PSD the objective is convex (note that this is a maximization problem, hence convexity does not help). I don't know what you mean by "reduces to the binary case"; the non-zero entries of $\mathbf{x}$ need not be equal to $1$ (at most one entry could be equal to $1$ anyways) or to each other (even for the optimal $\mathbf{x}$). That would depend on $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: @m.a. When maximizing a unary convex function on $[0,1]$, isn't it true that the maximum value is attained at $0$ or $1$? Forgive me if I've got some basic things wrong.

Comment: @WillardZhan If I was maximizing over the hypercube or the polytope defined by restricting each coordinate in $[0,1]$ that would be true. But here we have a $l_{2}$ constraint on $\mathbf{x}$. At the optimal $\mathbf{x}$, for arbitrary PSD $\mathbf{A}$, the entries of $\mathbf{x}$ could have arbitrary real values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I have found the answer to my question, so I am sharing a sketch here)*.

The quadratic maximization can be shown to be NP-hard by a reduction from the following problem:

- Given $k$-partite graph $G=(V_{1}, \dots, V_{k}, E)$, does $G$ contain a $k$-clique.

Note that the latter problem is a (seemingly) special case of the max-clique problem restricted to a particular family of graphs. It can however be shown that it is also NP-complete by a reduction from the general max-clique problem itself [(See here)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/k-clique-in-k-partite-graph).

Let $\mathbf{A}$ denote the adjacency matrix of $G$.
Let $S$ be an arbitrary set of $k$ vertices and $\mathbf{A}_{S}$ denote the principal submatrix corresponding to $S$, *i.e.* $\mathbf{A}_{S}$ is the $k\times k$ adjacency of the graph induced by $S$.
If the vertices in $S$ form a $k$-clique in $G$, then all off-diagonal entries of $\mathbf{A}_{S}$ are equal to $1$, and its principal eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}(\mathbf{A}_{S}) = k-1$.
In any other case, that is, if $S$ is not a $k$-clique, then $\lambda_{1}(\mathbf{A}_{S}) < k-1$.
Finally, note that since $G$ is $k$-partite, a $k$-clique (if one exists) will contain a single vertex from each of the sets $V_{i}$, $i=1,\dots,k$.

Let $\mathbf{A}^{\prime} = \mathbf{A} + |\lambda_{n}(\mathbf{A})|\cdot\mathbf{I}$, where $\lambda_{n}(\mathbf{A})$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$; 
$\mathbf{A}^{\prime}$ is a PSD matrix.
Further, consider $k$ disjoint groups of variables corresponding to the sets $V_{1}, \dots, V_{k}$ of $G$.
We solve the quadratic maximization with input $\mathbf{A}^{\prime}$ and the specified groups of variables.
The maximum objective value will be equal to $k-1 + |\lambda_{n}(\mathbf{A})|$ if and only if $G$ contains a $k$-clique.